# Migrating from DropBox to OneDrive/SharePoint

Tags: migration, sharepoint, dropbox

We currently have a DropBox that is used by 60 people. They all use the same login account. We currently use Exchange and would like to make use of the OneDrive and SharePoint option to implement SSO.

I want to create groups for ACL based accessed.

How does SharePoint differ then OneDrive? We currently have used the SharePoint for pages but when it comes to file sharing you have to use the OneDrive option correct so that users can upload and manage files within their group?

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive for Business (not to be confused with the consumer version) can be thought of as the general "My Documents" folder. Users can access these files from anywhere and can easily share the document for collaboration without having to email around documents and manually manage versions.

Because OneDrive for Business is a part of SharePoint, you get all the features of SharePoint: access control, file versioning, backups of files, metadata, file sync, etc. Team sites are useful for collaboration on team projects with a large number of documents that you want to share and collaborate on. OneDrive for Business sites usually have more scoped sharing. Under the hood, both are SharePoint sites.